# Shiny permissions: Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open file '../file_name.js': Permission denied

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use write() within a Shiny app on Shiny server. The folder containing the app has the right permissions, I believe:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 shiny  shiny  4096
```

i.e., before, I tried running both:

> sudo chown -R shiny /srv/shiny-server/app_name
>
> sudo chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server/app_name

However, on loading the app in the browser, calling write() fails. The log shows:

> Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :   cannot open file
> '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/my_package/www/js/file_name.js':
> Permission denied

The command works outside the context of the app, in a normal R session.

What could be going wrong here, given that I gave the app directory the correct permissions?

Comment: Your `chown` calls reference `/srv/shiny-server/app_name`, but the warning references `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/...`. It seems likely that you have installed the package as root or some other non-`shiny` user under `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` and it is (typically) not world-writable.

Comment: Side note: writing to a package directory from within a shiny app seems like a really bad idea. I'd think the javascript file should either (a) be included in the package initially so that the shiny app doesn't need to append it, or (b) included within a `./www/...` manifest within the shiny app itself; see https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/packaging-javascript.html

Comment: Hm, how should I do this then? If I do e.g., $ sudo su - shiny
$ R
$ install.packages("my_package"), I don't have permission to install the package. (Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’)

Comment: Are you trying to install a package or write a JavaScript file?  Your question says the latter, your comment the former.  Installing a package is a server admin problem, not an R problem.  If you're trying to write a JavaScript file, then @r2evans' comments apply.

Comment: I cannot fathom one situation where an R user overwriting or adding files to an installed package directory is a good idea, whether used in `shiny` or not. But ... I agree with Limey, your errors/warnings/problems seem to be shifting a bit.

Comment: It may not be the best idea, but that is not the question (and you don't know the full context). @r2evans suggested the issue was having installed the package with root was the issue, so I inferred that the solution was to install the package with shiny. However, ironically, the shiny user does not have permissions to install packages. So I meant to ask r2evans how I could implement their suggestion.

Comment: @eartoolbox, it isn't clear what the real issue is, tbh. The warning in your question could be because the `/usr/local/...` path is not writeable by user `shiny`, or it could because the package doesn't exist. This second possibility is supported by your comment saying that you cannot install packages there. Installation of packages to `/usr/local/...` can be done either by changing the permission of that main directory or by running `R` as root and controlling the location with `install.packages("my_package", lib="/usr/local/lib/R/site-packages")`.

Comment: Once installed, though, the permissions on the package directory are still likely to be not-`shiny`-writable, but if you really want to introduce that security hole into your server, then you know how to use `chown` on `/usr/local/lib/R/site-packages/my_package`. I hope for your case that this is not deploying to a large user-base (or even worse, the internet as a whole), as the potential for problem is not insignificant. Good luck!